# Power Query M - An operation that uses the database driver could not be completed

Tags: excel, powerquery, m

From time to time when I run some queries I get this error message :

> An operation that uses the database driver could not be completed. If the driver is a Microsoft driver, make sure the driver file isn't damaged

[image: the message error I get]

I didn't found yet how to fix it with internet help.
this last [website](https://msdynamicsaxtips.blogspot.com/2017/11/an-operation-that-uses-database-driver.html) give a "solution" but I can't do the same.

> "Well in my case it worked by giving the user access to the DB it is accessing."

I just have a worksheet who use others files from my company network, I don't use any database ...
I can't reinstall the driver or anything else, my company have a very strict politic about IT security.

May I have some help ?

Comment: Seems to me that if you have a broken driver, and IT won't let you repair it, you are out of luck.  How is the data you are accessing stored? Please post the code you are using to access this?  Sharepoint? Azure? etc.

Comment: I tried my query in 5 differents computer of my company, each time I get the same error. I don't think the 5 drivers are broken .... Also I'm not using any Database, I just try to open some excel files from the company network. I can open or edit these files by myself.

Comment: I can't share some code because my query is calling some functions so it's too much code to share

Comment: With no code and no information as to exactly how the file is stored on your company database, I cannot help you further.  Good Luck!

Comment: @Xodarap make sure you save the excel sheet as `.xlsx` , then try importing with `Power Query` -- You can check your drivers if you go to the `start menu` -> type `odbc` . It should have excel under the 64bit driver page. -- "I can't share my code, calls functions"  -- The query editor is smart, it will [copy **all queries and functions that are used** into one page](https://ninmonkeys.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/exporting-powerquery-to-vs-code-2020-10-07.mp4.mp4).

Comment: someone [fixed it by removing old connections](Opening in Excel, on the Data tab -> Connections, there was the old connection )

Comment: thank you all for you're support, here is a file with my code : https://ufile.io/jg01im78 it's available for 30 days from now. I hope it will help.

Comment: I checked the driver and it looks OK,

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when I try to connect Analysis service in Azure. The error message is misguiding. In actual, you are missing few client drivers that are needed to connect to Azure Analysis services. Install all the missing drivers (OLEDB, AMO and ADOMD) from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/client-libraries?view=asallproducts-allversions#known-issues and you should be good to go.

I think OLEDB installation should suffice the need but I did all three to avoid future encounters related to other admin stuff. Check if OLEDB updated @ C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Analysis Services\AS OLEDB\140 by comparing msolap.dll version. Latest version as I write this is 15.1.108.23

Tip: 1) Try connecting to Analysis Service from Excel by following the steps - Data Menu  --> Get Data -->  From Database --> From Analysis Services. Follow the prompts by filling appropriate info. Bingo! You are in!
2) Wait for a while if still you can't connect after installing all drivers. I don't know the actual reason why but was able to connect next day.

Please mark this as an answer if it helps to solve your problem.
Good Luck!

Update - 1/5/2021
Today I face same ugly error again which made me to rethink what else could be gone wrong in the system. Later realized that I had restarted the machine and that removed the temp connection file referred by Excel file. Following the steps to reconnect under the Tip section in above instructions let me successfully in.

Comment: Note that they updated the driver on the page for V16, which broke my connections.
Any chance someone has a link for 15.1.108.23 ? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was resolved by removing a hardcoded username from another user from the connection string.